# how to set List item Height,width and Border for ListBox in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I need to set Height,Width and Border Color for Each list items in the Listbox. In the event that I set Setter Property 
it's setting for entire listbox. Be that as it may, I need to set every last rundown thing. Any one help me.

here's my code:

```
  <ListBox x:Name="lbOne" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,29,0,12" Width="215"  
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following piece of code and let me know if it works for you.

```
<ListBox ...>
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Also, please refer the followings link for reference.

- [Stretch ListBox Items hit area to full width of the ListBox? ListBox style is set implicity through a theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634196/stretch-listbox-items-hit-area-to-full-width-of-the-listbox-listbox-style-is-se)
- [Silverlight 3: ListBox DataTemplate HorizontalAlignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746190/silverlight-3-listbox-datatemplate-horizontalalignment)

Probably, refer to the below link for using the ListBox Item properties appropriately.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062(v=vs.95).aspx